# How can I select the literal value and the IRI type on Blazegraph workbench?

Tags: sparql, blazegraph

I have a SPARQL query that selects the position given a source. Below is an example of a triple out of the millions in the file.

Triple:

```
<origin://123@12> <http://example.org/example#position> "16977"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer> .
```

The query I have written:

```
select  ?origin ?pos where {
  ?origin <http://example.org/example#position> ?pos . } limit 10
```

This gives me the output:

```
origin            | pos

<origin://123@12> | 16977
```

But the output I want is:

```
origin            | pos

<origin://123@12> | "16977"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer>
```

Is there a way to do this? I am using Blazegraph and the primary reason for this is, I want the literal type to be able to identify integers and floats for further processing.

Comment: I don't think there is an option for neither CSV or TSV as resultset format as both encode literals like SPARQL resp. Turtle do, thus, integer numbers omit the datatype.  If you ask for SPARQL JSON resultset format the datatype should be encoded

Comment: So what you are saying is that I won't be able to sort of append the IRI with the literal value like how these triples are represented in any given NQ file? @UninformedUser Like my only aim is to get the IRI type along with the plain Literal value, instead of just that value in the output.

Comment: with SELECT queries, use SPARQL+JSON as resultset format or you use a CONSTRUCT query and use N-Triples as format or in your `SELECT` query, you create a 3rd column that explicitely contains the datatype URI, i.e `select  ?origin ?pos (datatype(?pos) as ?dt) where`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`datatype()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-datatype), you can output a value’s datatype IRI:

```
SELECT ?origin ?pos ?pos_datatype
WHERE {
  ?origin <http://example.org/example#position> ?pos . 
  BIND( datatype(?pos) AS ?pos_datatype ) .
} LIMIT 10
```

```
SELECT ?origin ?pos ( datatype(?pos) AS ?pos_datatype )
WHERE {
  ?origin <http://example.org/example#position> ?pos . 
} LIMIT 10
```